# React Styled Components: ReferenceError: Cannot access before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

`SharedButton` is the base style of a button inside my app, and it is shared across components. I am trying to override the styles of this button inside `MyComponent`.

I am getting the following error when `myComponent` mounts:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SharedButton' before initialization`.

Note that If I don't import `SharedButton` from a different file, ie. if I define it inside "MyComponent", I don't get the error. How can I solve this issue?

shared.ts

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const SharedButton = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #1c101e;
  font-size: 14px;
`;
```

myComponent.ts

```
import { SharedButton } from "./shared";
import styled from "styled-components";

const MyComponentButton = styled(SharedButton)`
  float: right;
`;

const MyComponent = () => {
   return <MyComponentButton> TEST </MyComponentButton>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the `MyComponentButton` style in **shared.ts**  and export to the **myComponent.ts**. [sandbox examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-dawn-k3hfi?file=/src/Shared.js:27-40)

**shared.ts**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const SharedButton = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #1c101e;
  font-size: 14px;
`;

export const MyComponentButton = styled(SharedButton)`
  float: right;
`;
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
import { MyComponentButton } from "./shared";

const MyComponent = () => {
   return <MyComponentButton> TEST </MyComponentButton>
}
```

The second approach, put some props in **styled-components**

**shared.ts**

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const SharedButton = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #1c101e;
  font-size: 14px;
  ${({ floatRight }) =>
    floatRight &&
    css`
      float: left;
    `}
`;
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
import { SharedButton } from "./shared";
    
export const MyComponent = () => {
  return <SharedButton floatRight> TEST </SharedButton>;
};
```